# Remove space between numbers but leave for strings in R

Tags: r, string, split, gsub

I need to remove the spaces between numbers only, so that a string like this:

`"Hello 111 222 333 World!"`

becomes

`"Hello 111222333 World!"`

Any idea how to do this in R?

Comment: You can use e.g. [`str_replace_all(txt, '(\\d)\\s+(?=\\d)', '\\1')`](https://tio.run/##FYuxCoAgFAB3v@LVolIN6lq09gctD8JKInhUvBzq682247jjlGif2fOr7sj7sbEWIj4R2gbKIRCdYIwBay0452A8mdaiFCLHE4eL/BImT6TyUoNUiKtGvCvVdz/K7BCN1Cl9)

Comment: I saw that as well, however, I needed the code in R but thank you!

Answer (score 1):

An approach using a small replacement function together with `str_replace_all` while simply searching for numbers `[0-9]` and one or more spaces  `+`.

```
library(stringr)

repl <- function(x) sub(" ", "", x)

str_replace_all(stri, "[0-9] +[0-9]", repl)
[1] "Hello 111222333 World!"
```

##### Data

```
stri <- "Hello 111 222 333 World!"
```